# Is it a Poisson or an Exponential distribution?

Tags: inference, poisson-distribution, exponential-distribution

**I have to do statistical inference (homework) on following data and I am struggling to choose if I should go with an exponential or a poisson distribution to do my analysis.
Can you give me any hints?**

I am worried to get this wrong by choosing discrete in favor continuous or vice versa.

I have the following stackoverflow data: elapsed time between question posted and accepted answer posted on stackoverflow from 2020.

*edit: I could use this data to e.g. find the probability that my question will be answered within the first 20-40-60-... minutes*

histogram of data is as follows.

- x axis: elapsed time (in minutes) for accepted answer posted for a particular questin
- y axis: number of posts for which the accepted answer was created within that time interval

[image]

pandas density chart as follows:
[image]

Comment: A Poisson distribution is a probability distribution over non-negative integers. But the duration elapsed between two times is not an integer, so it's hard to see how this would be Poisson. // As with all questions about choosing a "name-brand" distribution for some data, the crucial question is *Why do you need to know this?* What are you trying to do, and how does identifying the distribution help you solve that problem?

Comment: Thanks @Sycorax, I added to the question: "I could use this data to find the probability that my question will be answered within the first 20-40-60-... minutes". And this is a homework to use statistical inference to try and find the properties of this distribution. I could go with the hypothesis that this is a normal distribution, and conclude this is not, but obviously I'd like to go with something that makes sense.

Comment: If you only need to estimate the probability of a question being answered before some amount of time, then you don't necessarily need to estimate a parametric distribution. You can use the ecdf: [tag:empirical-cumulative-distr-fn]

Comment: Do you have the unbinned data? That is, instead of knowing that it took $20$ to $40$ minutes, do you have values like $25$ and $31?$

Comment: Yes @Dave, I have, that is what the second plot is made of which is an estimated density function. and it is more similar to a poisson density curve

Comment: I cannot identify any Poisson distribution that might look like this one.  Which parameter do you have in mind as a good candidate?